# Открытие файла по ссылке html

Tags: php, html

Я вывожу путь к файлу из базы данных

```
$select_path="SELECT NameFile,FilePath FROM in_myfile WHERE DocumentNumber='$CardName' AND SelectionDescription = '$SelectionDescription'";
$var=mysqli_query($conn, $select_path);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($var))
{
    $file_name=$row["NameFile"];
    $file_path=$row["FilePath"];
    echo "<a href=".$file_path."/".$file_name.">$file_name</a><p></p>";
}
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы по нажатии на ссылку происходило открытие или просмотр данного файла? Если будет проще, то это документация, хранящаяся на сервере по пути, выводимому из бд.
Или каким вообще способом это возможно сделать?

Comment: базовую директорию файлов залинковать в корень сайта например

Comment: @teran а можно пример, я просто не очень понимаю, о чем вы

Answer (score 1):

немного не понятно как именно ты хочешь это сделать но один из лучших вариантов, это **Google Docs Viewer**, лучший вариант для того чтобы демонстрировать документы
Либо ссылкой

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={URL документа}" target="_blank"></a>
```

Либо используешь iframe

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={URL документа}"; width="700" height="820" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Подробнее про него тут [habr \ Google Docs Viewer](https://habr.com/ru/post/111647/)

Comment: делаю вот так: echo '<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={H:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/files/9611757.pdf}"  target="_blank" >'.$file_name.'</a><p></p>'; Но не находит этот url, хотя если просто его введу в поисковую строку этот url , все отображает

Comment: @findley Во первых проблема в том что у вас все хранится на локальном сервере, во вторых без вот этих скобочке {} т.е. `href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com"`

Comment: так мне и нужно, чтобы все хранилось на локальном сервере, а не в облаке=(

Comment: А смысл, если открыть сможете только вы ?

Comment: почему только я? Я делаю локальный сайт, и любой, кому нужно будет посмотреть документ, хранящийся на сервере, сможет это сделать, нет?

Comment: А все, если использовать такой путь,то все работает http://localhost/files/9611757.pdf